# Button Clicked function error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, object, xamarin, dialog

I have a simple dialog fragment with a cancel and save button. When cancel is clicked dialog is dismissed. And when I clicked save button an error occur saying. "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't really understand where I got it wrong.

Here is my axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Set the number of days:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/setnumDays" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfDays"
        android:layout_below="@+id/setnumDays"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/numberOfDays"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/numberOfDays"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="Save" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My dialog fragment is:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MedAlert.Activities;
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
//using TaskStackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using V7Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using Android.OS;

namespace MedAlert.Fragments
{
    public class DurationDialog : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
    {
        EditText numOfdays;

        public DurationDialog()
        {
            this.RetainInstance = true;
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_duration, container, false);

            var cancel = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.cancel);
            var save = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.save);
            numOfdays = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.numberOfDays);

            cancel.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                Dialog.Dismiss();
            };

            save.Click += Save_Click;

            return view;
        }

        void Save_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (addMedFragment.mode == "ADD") {
                try{
                    addMedFragment.duration = Int32.Parse(numOfDays.Text);
                    Dialog.Dismiss ();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    Dialog.Dismiss ();
                }
            }
            if (addMedFragment.mode == "EDIT"){
                try{
                    EDmedFragment.duration = Int32.Parse(numOfDays.Text);
                    Dialog.Dismiss ();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    Dialog.Dismiss ();
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help. I really need to solve this one before the week ends. Thanks!
Having these on my application output tab:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid] at MedAlert.Fragments.DurationDialog.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Android.OS.Bundle) [0x0003e] in c:\Users\xhemMiaow~\Documents\Projects\MedAlert\MedAlert\Fragments\DurationDialog.cs:34
[MonoDroid] at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0x000fa>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.9e951dbb-09ac-4bc9-accc-8ff86fa9323b (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00023, 0x00047>
```

Comment: what line does it occur on?

Comment: addMedFragment.duration = Int32.Parse(numOfDays.Text); and EDmedFragment.duration = Int32.Parse(numOfDays.Text); these lines from my DialogFragment.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Studio @DavidPilkington

Comment: But if i pass a number directly to addMedFragment.duration and EDMedFragment.duration, it works okay.

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem. It is in my EditText variable. Somehow when I tried assigning values to numOfDays.Text it gives the Object. . blah. . blah errors. But I still don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: Having these on my application output tab:

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText is named numOfdays (small 'd').
I don't know where and how numOfDays (with capital 'D') is defined and why don't you get a compiler error, but anyway I think it is always null, since you never assign a value to it. Sometimes these errors just need another eyes to be seen :-)